# Simple AJAX Request and Response in Symfony2

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, twig

I've got a 'create' form in Symfony and by putting in some informations in textarea, the controller should just process the request and response it respectfully.

The AJAX call is made in an twig template:

```
{% block content_foot_script %}
<script>
    function fetchData() {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", "{{ path('receiptFetchSystem') }}", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var data = $("#admin_store_receipt_receiptbundle_receipt_objects").val();
        xhttp.send('items=' + data);

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.success && xhttp.code == 200) {
                document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

and the `ReceiptFetchController` handles the requests:

```php
<?php

namespace Admin\Store\Receipt\ReceiptBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class ReceiptFetchController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/call", name="receiptFetchSystem")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function callAction()
    {
        $request = $this->container->get('request');
        $data = $request->request->get('items');

        $response = array("code" => 200, "success" => true);
        return new Response($response);    
    }

}
```

Well, as expected, I'm getting no response :)

Best regards

Comment: what happens when you add a `use` statement for the Symfony Response class?

Comment: What is `xhttp.success`? Also encode your data properly... `xhttp.send('items=' + encodeURIComponent(data));`

Comment: actually the check is `if (xhttp.responseType == 4 && xhttp.status  == 200) {` your response is not attached to the xhr object

Comment: Musa there are no results... I've changed the code. I think the problem might be in AJAX call. `fetchData()` is called by `onchange` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've made it working by changing some codes, here they are:

ReceiptFetchController.php:

```
<?php

namespace Admin\Store\Receipt\ReceiptBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ReceiptFetchController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/call", name="receiptFetchSystem")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function callAction()
    {
        $request = $this->container->get('request');

        $items = $request->request->get('items');
        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        $itemsList = preg_split('/\r\n|[\r\n]/', $items);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AdminStoreProductProductBundle:Product');
        $productsList = array();
        foreach ($itemsList as $key){
            $product =$em->findOneBy(array('barCode' => $key));
            if ($product) {
                $productDetail['Price'] = $product->getSalesPrice();
                $productDetail['Type'] = $product->getType()->getSlugify();
                $productDetail['Name'] = $product->getName();
                $productsList[] = $productDetail;
            }

        }

        $response->setContent(json_encode($productsList));
        return $response;
    }

}
```

and here is the view file:

```
{% block content_head_script %}
    <script>
        function fetchData() {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var data = $("#admin_store_receipt_receiptbundle_receipt_objects").val();
            xhttp.open("POST", "{{ path('receiptFetchSystem') }}", true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhttp.send('items=' + (data));

            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                    TableGenerator(xhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
        }

        function TableGenerator(response) {
            var totalPrice = 0;
            var arr = JSON.parse(response);
            var i;
            var out = "";

            for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                out += "<tr><td>" +
                        arr[i].Price +
                        "</td><td dir='ltr'>" +
                        arr[i].Type +
                        "</td><td>" +
                        arr[i].Name +
                        "</td></tr>";

                totalPrice += arr[i].Price;
            }
            out += "<tr><td colspan='2' dir='ltr'><strong>جمع کل</strong></td><td>" + totalPrice + "</td></tr>";
            $('#tableBody').html(out);
        }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```